# using a variable with refer and matching to an array

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I have an input that validates if a string is unique. I have an array of already current values to check against. If the user inputs in all capitals I want it to still match as long as it’s exact. I tried doing a new regex constructor but there is no flag for returning only exact matches.

Here is what I have which returns dog and doggy. I just want dog.

```
let myarray = [‘dog’ , ‘doggy’, ‘cat’]

let value = ‘dog’

let reg = new RegExp(value, 'i');


let tag = myarray.filter(function (str) { return reg.test(str); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find an exact word, add the matches beginning (`^` sign) before the value, and matches end (`$` sign) after the value:

```js
const myarray = ['dog', 'doggy', 'cat']

const value = 'dog'

const reg = new RegExp(`^${value}$`, 'i');

const tag = myarray.filter((str) => reg.test(str));

console.log(tag);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.